# Neo4j 3.0.1, proper way to restore backup by copying binary files (graph.db)

Tags: neo4j

I am running `neo4j` v.3.0.1 and I want to restore an old backup (of another version of neo4j) by moving the old `graph.db` directory.

In my `neo4j.conf` I have:

```
# Paths of directories in the installation.
dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
dbms.allow_format_migration=true
```

If copy `graph.db` in `/var/lib/neo4j/data`, the restore does not work, but a new folder called `graph.db` is automatically created in `/var/lib/neo4j/databases` after I start the service.

If I copy the backup folder directly in `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases`, the restore is successful. I do not understand why, since I set `dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `databases` is implicitly appended to the `dbms.directories.data` path. That is a change in 3.0.

Comment: Thanks! Just read that change in https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.0-changelog Anyway probably this concept should be explicated in comment near `dbms.directories.data` in `neo4j.conf` if it is not already done